# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined nexjs reudux and PersistGate

Tags: reactjs, redux, next.js

Error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined I try Migrating from Create React App but cant use redux I tried many ways but still can't fix it. -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

[image: Error Image]
_app.js

```js
import "../styles/globals.css";
import App from "next/app";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import React from "react";
import reduxStore from "../redux/store/store";
import { reduxPersistor} from "../redux/store/store";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { appWithTranslation } from "next-i18next";
import theme from "../theme";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Layout from "../components/layouts/Layout";
import { Provider as AlertProvider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from "../components/alert/alert.component.jsx";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import withRedux from "next-redux-wrapper";
const Pace = dynamic(
  () => {
    return import("../components/customs/pace/pace.js");
  },
  { ssr: false }
);
class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    return {
      pageProps: {
        // Call page-level getInitialProps
        ...(Component.getInitialProps
          ? await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
          : {}),
      },
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // let app = databaserealtime.ref("/maintenance/maintenancestatus");
    // app.on("value", (snapshot) => {
    //   this.setState({
    //     maintenancestatus: snapshot.val(),
    //   });
    // if (snapshot.val() === 1) {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (userAuth) => {
      this.setState({ currentUser: userAuth });
      if (userAuth) {
        const userRef = await createUserProfileDocument(userAuth);
        userRef.onSnapshot((snapShot) => {
          this.props.setCurrentUser({
            id: snapShot.id,
            ...snapShot.data(),
          });
        });
      }
    });
    // }
    // });
    // this.props.i18n.changeLanguage(this.props.lang);

    // this.unsubscribeFromAnnounce = this.getAnnounceText();
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribeFromAuth && this.unsubscribeFromAuth();
    // this.unsubscribeFromAnnounce && this.unsubscribeFromMaintenanceStatus();
    // this.unsubscribeFromAnnounce && this.unsubscribeFromAnnounce();
    // this.unsubscribeFromAnnounce && this.getAnnounceText();
  }
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, store } = this.props;
    const options = {
      timeout: 10000,
    };
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={reduxPersistor}>
            <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
              <Pace color={theme.palette.primary.main} />
              <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>
                <Layout>
                  <Component {...pageProps} />
                </Layout>
              </AlertProvider>
            </ThemeProvider>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
// const mapStateToProps = ({ user, language }) => ({
//   currentUser: user.currentUser,
//   lang: language.lang,
// });
const mapStateToProps = (state) => console.log(state);
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  setCurrentUser: (user) => dispatch(setCurrentUser(user)),
  setI18n: (lang) => dispatch(setI18n(lang)),
});
export default withRedux(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(appWithTranslation(MyApp));
```

store.js

```js
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "../root-reducer";
import { persistStore } from "redux-persist";
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
const logger = createLogger();
let middleware = [];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  middleware = [...middleware, logger];
} else {
  middleware = [...middleware];
}

export const reduxStore = createStore(rootReducer, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)));
export const reduxPersistor = persistStore(reduxStore,{});
```

root-reducer.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import userReducer from "./user/user.reducer";
import i18nReducer from "./i18n/i18n.reducer";
import currencyReducer from "./currency/currency.reducer";
const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
  whitelist: ["language", "currency"],
};
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  language: i18nReducer,
  currency: currencyReducer,
});
export default persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

Answer (score 0):

try in provider to change store to reduxStore
because you import reduxStore from "../redux/store/store" but store is just an undefined in the props